# How do I tell jQuery UI datepicker the year when the dateFormat doesn't include it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create two date inputs and not show the year inside the date field. I want the format to be easier to read - so "Fri, Apr 19" rather than "2013/4/19". I am storing the more conventional format in an alternate field that gets updated at the same time. This works fine, apart from when I select a date in a future year and then go back to click on that same date input. It loads up a date in the current year instead. This is some test code to show the situation and my attempts at working around the behaviour.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="from" id="ff_from" class="date" value=""  />
    <input type="text" name="to" id="ff_to" class="date" value="" />
    <div class="extra">
        <p>Formatted version of dates</p>
        <input type="text" disabled id="ff_from_formatted" value="" />
        <input type="text" disabled id="ff_to_formatted" value="" />
    </div>
</form>

<script>
// add n number of days
Date.prototype.addDays = function(n) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate()+n);
    return this;
};

$("#ff_from").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "D, M dd",
    altField:$("#ff_from_formatted"),
    altFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    minDate:0,
    onClose:function(){
        $("#ff_to").focus();
    }
}).change(function(){
    var fromDate=new Date($("#ff_from_formatted").val());
    var toDate=new Date($("#ff_to_formatted").val());
    minToDate=fromDate.addDays(1);
    if (fromDate >= toDate) {
        $("#ff_to").datepicker("setDate", minToDate);
    }
    $("#ff_to").datepicker("option","minDate", minToDate);
});
$("#ff_to").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "D, M dd",
    altField:$("#ff_to_formatted"),
    altFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    minDate:+1
});
</script>
```

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpfAB/9/

To reproduce the problem

1. Select a date in the first field that is in 2014
2. Click on the input field again. It will load up the current date instead.

---

EDIT: final solution below is thanks to help from @clav - this involved removing the altFields and using hidden input fields instead. I used opacity:0 instead of display:none, because I was getting odd errors on the ff_to field when using display:none.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpfAB/33/

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="ff_from_display" class="date"/>
    <input type="text" name="from" id="ff_from" class="date" style="opacity:0;width:0;"/>
    <input type="text" id="ff_to_display" class="date"/>
    <input type="text" name="to" id="ff_to" class="date" style="opacity:0;width:0;" />
</form>

<script>
// add n number of days
Date.prototype.addDays = function(n) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate()+n);
    return this;
};

$('#ff_from_display').focus(function() {
    $("#ff_from").datepicker('show');
});

$('#ff_to_display').focus(function() {
    $("#ff_to").datepicker('show');
});

$("#ff_from").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    minDate:0,
    onClose:function(){  
        $("#ff_to_display").focus();
    }
}).change(function(){
    var fromDate = $("#ff_from").datepicker('getDate');
    $('#ff_from_display').val($.datepicker.formatDate('D, M dd', fromDate));
    var toDate=new Date($("#ff_to_formatted").val());
    minToDate=fromDate.addDays(1);
    if (fromDate >= toDate) {
        $("#ff_to").datepicker("setDate", minToDate);
    }
    $("#ff_to").datepicker("option","minDate", minToDate);
});

$("#ff_to").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    minDate:+1
}).change(function(){
    var toDate = $("#ff_to").datepicker('getDate');
    $('#ff_to_display').val($.datepicker.formatDate('D, M dd', toDate));
});
</script>
```

Comment: try to have a look in this [link] (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) and [link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year)

Comment: @sentilkumar that is not equivalent, because the year is in the dateformat there. As a result the datepicker handles it fine. I'm trying to not show the year inside the date input.

Comment: U just try add at minDate:0 to **minDate:0 + 365** and  minDate:+1 to  **minDate:+1 + 365**. It just a way but im not sure it helps you or not.

Comment: I don't want to set the minDate. That would stop the user from choosing an earlier date which is not a desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug with the date picker, even if the date is manually set to the correct date in the `beforeShow` function, the year still displays incorrectly. One workaround that's a bit of a hack is to set the format to something that does include the year, then hide the datepicker input field, create a different text field to display the date and show the datepicker when the user clicks the "display" field.  Then in the `onClose` callback you can set the value of the display field by formatting the selected date using `$.datepicker.formatDate('D, M dd', date)`.  Something like this:

```
<!-- new display field that will show the selected date in "D, M dd" format -->
<input type="text" id="ff_display" class="date"/> 
<!-- hide the real datepicker text field -->
<input type="text" name="from" id="ff_from" class="date" style="display: none;"/>

// show the datepicker when the user clicks the visible "display" date field
$('#ff_display').click(function() {
    $("#ff_from").datepicker('show');
});

$("#ff_from").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd", // date format contains year so it won't get lost
    gotoCurrent: true,
    altField:$("#ff_from_formatted"),
    altFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    onClose:function(){  
        // get the selected date, put it in nice format and set value of display field
        var date = $("#ff_from").datepicker('getDate');
        $('#ff_display').val($.datepicker.formatDate('D, M dd', date));
        $("#ff_to").focus();
    }
.... rest of datepicker init code
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpfAB/29/), I just did the first date but you can see how this same logic can be applied to the other date field.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution. I did try setting the date with beforeShow initially and found it just ignored that. This solution really renders the altField useless, so I'm trying to rewrite it now without that.

Comment: My final jsfiddle here (some css issues clearly, but it does the right thing)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpfAB/33/